# How can I say "school/university of life" in Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation

I want to translate "school/university of life" into Latin. Meaning, where you learn about life.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

*Schola vitae* is attested, especially in Medieval Latin.

Examples include *Doctrina [est] schola vitae*, or (from Ephemerides Liturgicae) *Praxis genuina liturgiae est schola vitae interioris*.

Comment: Thanks for the response